# SharePoint 2010 Context menu stop working until page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Problem: Using SharePoint 2010 in IE 8; the default context menu like document library items menue works only once on each page then stop responding unless the page is refreshed.

The status bar error shows - "Javascript:;"  and nothing else.

Java scripting is enables in IE, the sharepoint portal is in trusted sites.

What could that be?  Any hints?

Thanks,
Val

Comment: What doesn it mean "works only once" — once per page load? How often does it occur? Consistently? Most likely some unloaded JavaScript / network issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the zoom size? I have had a similar problem with list items and was able to recreate it when the zoom setting was set to 125 %. The problem went away when I set the zoom setting to 100 %. This is odd and unexpected but it worked...

Another approach/test would be to see if this problem occurs with IE 9.

Comment: No, the zoom factor was not an issue.  After spending a lot of time, i simply re-install the web part and the library view.  All went away.  Oh, well, SharePoint gremlins again...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem, and after some hours of search, I finally found that it comes from the ToolbarType parameter of my XsltListViewWebpart.
Set on Standard, I have the problem, but if I set FreeForm, it works !

I think it is a bug of SharePoint 2010.

Hope this will help.

Some articles that helped :

[Here is an article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e5f4650-3ce5-4aaa-a750-7d7a31211fef/xsltlistviewwebpart-item-drop-down-not-working-second-click?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

[Another one](http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2015/09/22/programmatically-setting-toolbar-type-for-list-view-web-part-sharepoint/)

[A last one](https://bertrandvergnault.sharepoint.com/blog/Lists/Billets/Post.aspx?ID=48)

[The solution in my case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eae6d14b-639d-4c23-989c-704f742423ba/adding-xsltlistviewwebpart-on-page-context-menu-issue-in-folders-sp2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious#d34c43f6-c0f3-4913-a2a8-1552a6fed672) (Just setting the ToolbarType was not enough, I had to Apply the changes on the webpart)